# Can't get min-width max-width searchbar to behave correctly

Tags: css, searchbar

Been trying for hours to get the searchbar to default at 500px and downsize with the screen until it reaches 200px all while remaining centered. I want it to be mobile friendly. I have been trying different methods of implementation for hours and fail to see why it wont work.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="search-container">
           <div class="search">
                <form id="search-form">
                    <input class="searchbar" title="Search" placeholder="Search"/>
                </form>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS: see: http://jsfiddle.net/3dXD5/

Comment: You should include the CSS in the question as well - it's great to have a fiddle to work with, but the question should include enough information to stand on its own. See this discussion for more details http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Answer (score 0):

Inline-block elements won't by default fill their container, so you need to set the `width` property on your container as well as `min-width` and `max-width`.

The `width` property tells the element to "try" to be 100%, but `max-width` and `min-width` override `width` and clamp the value within the range you're specifying.

```
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 200px;
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3dXD5/1/

Note, I also removed the `margin` on the inner element because having a 100% `width` on that combined with a `margin` was pushing it off-centre. If you want to re-introduce that spacing, one way would be to remove the `display:inline-block` and `width:100%` from the `search` div (it will then naturally fill its container), and add `padding` there.